# Return key name of array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i have data from API and all works perfectly but how can i get key name only to fetch outside map ?

**this is my data json**

```
[
  {
      "topic": "HAIRPORT",
      "percentage": 90
  }, 
  {
      "topic": "TECHTRIX",
      "percentage": 67
  }
]
```

**and this is my current code**

```
const data = this.state.topics;
console.log(data)
```

All i want to get key name Percentage and Topic outside **map** or **for**

so here is i upload the images[image]

Comment: this question need improvements, it is very unclear what you are asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use :

```
Object.keys(this.state.topics[0])
```

```js
const data = [
  {
      "topic": "HAIRPORT",
      "percentage": 90
  }, 
  {
      "topic": "TECHTRIX",
      "percentage": 67
  }
]

const keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

console.log(keys);
console.log(keys[0]);
console.log(keys[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array then use `for..in` to find the key in each object. Try the following way:

```js
var data = [
  {
      "topic": "HAIRPORT",
      "percentage": 90
  }, 
  {
      "topic": "TECHTRIX",
      "percentage": 67
  }
];
data.forEach(function(item, i){
  for(var key in item)
    console.log(key)
});
```

Comment: Sorry my fault, all i want get the key outside for ? will update the question

Comment: @FreddySidauruk, from which index of the array you want keys?....Thanks.

Comment: @FreddySidauruk, you can use a variable to hold keys and use that variable anywhere you want.